# Back references for shorthandlist

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I am using `biblatex` for writing my thesis and it works generally fine. Now I want to put back references to my bibliography. However, after putting the option into the preamble, the back references only appear in the normal bibliography but not in the list of the shorthands. Does anyone know how to make the shorthand list including the back references?
Here is a mini example (compiled with `lualatex`, but I think the result is the same as with `latex`):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}

@book{Abook,
author = {First Author and The Second Author},
title = {The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle},
shorthand = {LnS},
publisher = {The Publisher},
address =  {Address},
year = {1965}}

@article{Aarticle,
author = {Article Author},
journal = {Journal Title},
pages = {113-126},
title = {Title of the Article},
volume = {65},
year = {1968}}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,backref=true,hyperref=true,language=auto,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}}

\bibliography{mybib}
\bibintoc
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}%english names of sections
\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
Backreference?
\cite{Abook}
\cite{Aarticle}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[check=noshorthand]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modifying the `shorthands` bibliography driver seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Abook,
author = {First Author and The Second Author},
title = {The Longtitle and not the Shorttitle},
shorthand = {LnS},
publisher = {The Publisher},
address =  {Address},
year = {1965}}

@article{Aarticle,
author = {Article Author},
journal = {Journal Title},
pages = {113-126},
title = {Title of the Article},
volume = {65},
year = {1968}}

\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,backref=true,hyperref=true,language=auto,autocite=inline]{biblatex}

\defbibcheck{noshorthand}{%
\iffieldundef{shorthand}{}{\skipentry}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\bibintoc
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}%english names of sections
\usepackage[babel,english=british]{csquotes}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{shorthands}{%
  \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock% NEW
  \usebibmacro{pageref}% NEW
  \finentry}

\begin{document}
Backreference?
\cite{Abook}
\cite{Aarticle}
\printshorthands
\printbibliography[check=noshorthand]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 This works because `\usedriver` locally sets the `bibindex` and `pageref` bibliography macros to `\@empty`.

Comment: Thank you lockstep, thank you Audrey! The solution provided by lockstep is working fine until now. It seems that biblatex has to provide an option for the backrefs in the list of shorthands.